# Declare globals for files matching pattern

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of test files that match `*.app-spec.ts`. I want to be able to declare certain globals for those files that are already pre-initialized in the global namespace, for example importing `expect` or `td` for testdouble.

Is there some way to provide a declaration files only for files matching that pattern?